# Why does removeChild function behave differently with list items and i tag?

Tags: javascript

I have noticed that removeChild does NOT behave as it does with other elements such as list item. I am using the i tag for some icons from frontAwesome and want these items removed individually when a button is clicked.

Unfortunately, I can only remove each i tag element only if I use removeChild() function twice. (Weird!)

What's going on?

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="myFonts">
        <i>1</i>
        <i>2</i>
        <i>3</i>
        <i>4</i>
        <i>5</i>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function FunctionTwo() {
    var font = document.getElementById("myFonts");
    font.removeChild(font.childNodes[0]);
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeaYvL

***EDIT***
Note: It makes a difference if you use LineBreaks or not!

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Here, there are 6 child nodes. Apparently, the LineBreaks are also considered as child nodes!

```
<ul id="myList"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li></ul>
```

Here, there are 3 child nodes. WEIRD - is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes),

> childNodes includes all child nodes, including non-element nodes like
>   text and comment nodes. To get a collection of only elements, use
>   ParentNode.children instead.

Hence, in both the cases, the elements are being removed weirdly. You should update

from

```
font.removeChild(font.childNodes[0]);
```

to

```
font.removeChild(font.children[0]);
```

For tweaking, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aazoLK

Comment: I just noticed that it maters if I write everything on one line or use PageBreaks. It will consider PageBreaks as nodes aswell. Thanks your solution is better.

Comment: @BitByBit - Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Also.. if you notice both of your code closely on your link...

Code for `<ul id="myList">`

`<ul id="myList"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li></ul>`

We see no spaces between tags.

Whereas, Code for `<div id="myFonts">`

`<div id="myFonts">
        <i>1</i>
        <i>2</i>
        <i>3</i>
        <i>4</i>
        <i>5</i>
  </div>`

You see the empty spaces before the `<i>`? Those got added as a text node in the childNodes object of your `div`

`<div id="myFonts">
        <i>1</i>
  </div>`

You could have used exactly the same code that you have currently, if you had chosen to rather Not add spaces before the `<i>` tags.

For Eg. like this:

`<div id="myFonts"><i>1</i><i>2</i><i>3</i><i>4</i><i>5</i></div>`

Check modified HTML for `div` here: 
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VGYLyN)